# Grab element attribute

Tags: javascript, html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am attempting to grab an attributes value when an element is clicked, however it seems as if the attribute is not being recognized. The HTML/element attributes are shown below:
[image: ELEMENT Attributes being Clicked]

I am getting a null value when trying to pull the 'data-url' value from the attribute (using google tag manager) when the element is clicked. Using hasAttribute is returning FALSE. Below is my javascript:

```
function() {
  return {{element}}.hasAttribute("data-url");
}
```

-->returning false

```
function() {
  return {{element}}.getAttribute("data-url");
}
```

-->returning NULL

Comment: Is the node a member of the same _#document_ as the script's defined source? I've had a weird behaviour before when I first needed to `document.importNode(node)` before I could access what I wanted

Comment: Also, what are you actually using for `{{element}}`? How are you querying the DOM for the node?